# Connecting extenders to an ethernet switch but keeping them as separate Wi-Fi networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, wired-networking

What I want is to use ethernet cables between an ethernet switch (3Com Baseline Switch 2952 SFP-Plus) and a few access points but I still want them to be separate networks.

The reason is that I have a some stuff such as printers that can be controlled via Wi-Fi  and I don't want people connected to one of the access points to be able to use a printer that is connected to another access point.

Is there some way I can configure the access points as routers and will that solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

What you want here is some VLANs.  Some APs may have the ability to apply access lists on the same flat network, but typically to have one AP's segment protected from another, VLANs are the way to go.  Since your switch appears to be a managed switch, you should have some VLAN functionality.

Now when you introduce VLANs, you're spitting your network up into segments, and in order to get from one segment to another you'll need to pass through a router.

You're in luck, because google says that your switch supports static routing as well.

Essentially what you want to do, is assign each AP connected switch port to a different VLAN, assign the switch an IP in each VLAN, configure the devices in each VLAN to use the switch's IP as their default gateway, and finally configure the switch's default gateway to be your internet firewall or router.  That device will also need routes back to the switch for each VLAN's subnet, so it knows where to return packets.

Once you do all that, it should just be a matter of applying some access rules on the switch to tell it what IPs can go to what destinations, and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

You have a managed switch, so create separate VLANs for different networks; all communications between subnets on different VLANs will need to go through your main router, which can have whatever firewall rules you need. Making the poor APs act as routers to achieve network separation would be just backwards.